# How to solve template error in Arcgis AR for iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, arcgis-runtime, esri-maps

I am trying to create an AR App for navigation, so i downloaded the templates suggested by arcgis for that, while there were no errors in xamarin.forms there are lot of namespace errors in xamarin.ios where i wanted to build my app, the errors are attached below[

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some import bug in Esri Xamarin.iOS templates alone, to rectify that problem, we need to go to Tools->Package Manager-> Manage Nuget Packages for solution->Search for all ArcGIS Packages-> once the search results are out, go to a ESRI.ArcGISRuntime package-> click the checkbox on the right where you will see it unchecked(in project version installed format)-> after checking the box you will find the install button select install-> Do it for all Esri.ArcGISRuntime packages and the errors will disappear.

If there is one error for "**using ArcGISRuntime**" use "**using ESRI.ArcGISRuntime**"